# Compiler won't recognize my custom class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, header-files

Here is my header file for Board:

```
#import "Game.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Board : UIView
{
    enum Piece;
}

- (void) setGame: (Game*) theGame; //<-- this is where the error is
typedef enum {X, O, NONE} Piece;
- (float)getSection;
@end
```

The compiler says "Expected a type" and has (Game*) underlined. What is the problem here?

---

Game.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Board.h"

@interface Game : UIViewController

- (void)boardwasTapped:(int) row:(int) column;

@end
```

Comment: It looks like `Game` isn't declared in `Game.h`.  Can you show that code?

Comment: Or maybe Game.h includes Board.h so there is a circular reference with no forward declaration. You should let us see Game.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import your header, but forward declare it. Import the Game header in Board.m

```
@class Game;

@interface Board : UIView {
...
}
...
@end
```

Also, are you sure the problem isn't with your enum? You are using it in your header before you declare it. You should declare it above (outside) the @interface block.

Answer (score 1):

Board import game, and Game import Board. So you need to forward class Game in Board

```
@Class Game
```